# Can B1B2 Visitor Visa Holder marry a person who has been waiting for her asylum interview in USA but alreday got her work permit and SSN

Tags: usa, immigration, canada, asylum

Hi Guys I am Permanent Resident of Canada ( Indian Passport Holder) living in British Columbia.  My Girlfriend has been waiting for her asylum interview in USA but she already got her work permit and SSN
Here are some questions Regarding Our Case:

Questions 1 - 3 duplicated at Law.SE.

4. If I can marry her with my B1B2 visa as she is not green card holder or citizen yet. Should I also have to wait 90 days in USA before marriage so that USCIS not consider it as misuse of my entry  in future when I apply for green card once she get her green card after completion of her asylum case .

[Question 5 duplicated at Law.SE.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/76460/can-b1b2-visitor-visa-holder-marry-a-person-who-has-been-waiting-for-her-asylum)

6. What would be the best possible solution for our case ? How should we proceed so that we don't have any kind of immigration problems for future?

Comment: Also asked at [Law.SE]: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/76460/333

Answer (score 1):

Since I already addressed all of the other questions at Law.SE, here's the last one:

> What would be the best possible solution for our case ? How should we proceed so that we don't have any kind of immigration problems for future.

Probably your best bet is to petition for immigration after she becomes a permanent resident.  You can marry any time before she submits the petition.

Comment: But it will be a long wait until she becomes a permanent resident. First, she has to wait until she is granted asylum, and then wait 1 year before she can apply for Adjustment of Status, and Adjustment of Status can take a year or so, before she becomes a permanent resident. On the other hand, if they marry before she is granted asylum, he can join her as a derivative asylee after she is granted asylum.

Comment: @user102008 yes, thanks for pointing that out.  It did occur to me that there might be some family reunification provision in the asylum laws, but I forgot to look it up and come back to edit the answers.